# Microsoft Visio Database add-in - Reverse Engineer of Azure Sql Server only showing 'master' Database and no others

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, reverse-engineering, visio, datamodel

I'm attempting to use the Visio Reverse Engineer wizard, part of the database add-in for Visio, targeting one of our databases that's an Azure SQL Database.

I'm able to successfully connect using the same connection strings that I use for all of our other services, SSMS, SSIS, Python, etc..., however the only DB option it gives me is 'master' [Master DB only Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJzbi.png). One connected it displays only objects in the master db which obviously I'm not trying to reverse engineer into a data model. [Master DB objects available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIZko.png)

Additionally, I've tried passing 'Catalog=' Parameter to point to the database in question but this gives me the same options.

All of our Azure SQL Databases have the connection string <*databasename>*.database.windows.net

I've used the Reverse Engineer wizard before for our other SQL Server (which is on an Azure VM and not a Azure SQL Database itself) with no problems.

At this point, I'm not sure if this is an issue with the Visio Reverse Engineer wizard or if there is some setting that we are missing with our Azure SQL Databases.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Connected to the correct instance? Does the login you're using have the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission, or has it been denied or revoked? If you type the database name instead, does it work?

Comment: Hi Larnu, I have successfully connected with both an Admin user account and our application user account, both of which have read access to all databases I'm attempting to Reverse Engineer a data model from. As far as 'type the database name instead', I'm a little confused what you mean. I've tried putting the database name in the connection string and it still only gives me access to objects in the master db.

Comment: Type your database name in the box that says `master`. And what do you mean by an admin with "read" access? Do you mean a `syadmin`? If not, like I said before, does the login have the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission m

Comment: The box that says master is a drop down and does not allow any text to be entered. Yes syadmin (Not sure of exact terminology I am not a DBA) is one of the accounts I have tried this with. Both accounts have VIEW ANY DATABASE permission. This is only an issue with Visio as far as I can tell. Credentials for both user logins I am attempting here can view all other databases with no issues for all of the other services we use.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When choosing what Visio DB Driver I wanted to use, I figured I'd try to use SQL Server Native Client 11.0 and it allowed me to select the DB I wanted to Reverse Engineer instead of just master db. [Driver Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RztI6.png)

I'm not certain why this worked for me, bit it did.

Comment: Since it worked and the error solved, you can accept it as the answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: This allowed me to connect but did not allow me to import anything other than tables (no views).